# Publish .net MAUI Application as windows executable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, publish, maui

How can I publish a .net MAUI Application to a Single executable? Is this even possible?
I Have an application which I want my friends to use on their Windows PC. Is there any way without using the command prompt?

Comment: if it's a UWP app, then you should be able to use the normal UWP publishing options

Comment: OR if its a "Windows Desktop" app, the answer is [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/overview). I haven't tried it yet - you might run into issues, given that both VS 2022 Preview and MAUI are .. Preview.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the new release of .net MAUI 6.0.400 (Service Release 1) you can build your application to a working exe file.
In Visual Studio:
Right click your solution, open in terminal.
Run the following command:

```
msbuild /restore /t:build /p:TargetFramework=net6.0-windows10.0.19041 /p:configuration=release /p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true /p:Platform=x64 /p:WindowsPackageType=None /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win10-x64
```

or if you want to target x86 for some legacy system:

```
msbuild /restore /t:build /p:TargetFramework=net6.0-windows10.0.19041 /p:configuration=release /p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true /p:Platform=x86 /p:WindowsPackageType=None /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win10-x86
```

The build exe (x64) file can be found in \bin\x64\release\net6.0-windows10.0.19041\win10-x64

Publishing to a single file is possible but currently a little bugged, for example images need to be copied from the build folder into the publish folder to work. Images used via Blazor in the wwwroot folder work without a problem though.

Publishing command:

```
msbuild /restore /t:Publish /p:TargetFramework=net6.0-windows10.0.19041 /p:configuration=release /p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true /p:Platform=x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:WindowsPackageType=None /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win10-x64
```

The build exe (x64) file can be found in \bin\x64\release\net6.0-windows10.0.19041\win10-x64\publish\

Comment: Did what you said and got error :sigh.   C:\Users\Gordon\source\repos\RouteIt\RouteIt.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "release|x64" is invalid.
Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuratio
n=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration. [C:\Users\Gordon\source\repos\Rout
eIt\RouteIt.sln]  Why is release x64 invalid, it is an 64 bit m/c

Comment: I've looked at the error and tried things, but no joy. I have set the drop down to release and built the solution from Build, build and I have a folder with hundreds of files and a RouteIt.exe but that doesn't do anything, even in situ.

Comment: Made progress by right clicking on the project folder and open in terminal. (Not the solution folder) No errors, but though this time when clicking on the exe file the app made a brief outline appearance it then closed.  Ahh now got an almost working exe from the first MSBuild line, single executable not working though.

Comment: @gfmoore try this command on your solution `dotnet publish -c Release -p:WindowsPackageType=None -p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true -p:Platform=x64` and tell me how it goes for you!

Comment: Sadly an error :)

PS ...> dotnet publish -c Release -p:WindowsPackageType=None -p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true -p:Platform=x64 MSBuild version 17.3.0-preview-22329-01+77c72dd0f for .NET Determining projects to restore... Restored

Comment: C:\Users\Gordon\source\repos\RouteIt\RouteIt.csproj (in 4.87 sec). C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400-preview.22330.6\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.CrossTargeting.targets(27,5): error NET SDK1129: The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework. The current project targets multiple frameworks, you m ust specify the framework for the published application. [C:\Users\Gordon\source\repos\RouteIt\RouteIt.csproj]

Comment: @gfmoore how bout `dotnet publish -c Release -p:WindowsPackageType=None -p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true -p:Platform=x64 -p:TargetFramework=net6.0-windows10.0.19041`

Comment: So sorry :(  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400-preview.22330.6\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolu
tion.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'C:\Users\Gordon\source\repos\RouteIt\obj\project.assets.json' do
esn't have a target for 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0-w
indows10.0.19041' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [C:\Users\Gordon\source\repos\RouteIt\RouteIt.csproj]

Comment: I note I'm getting a lot of warnings about a map package I'm using called Mapsui , but no errors. Maybe that's the problem, it isn't fully developed at the moment for Maui, though works fine from the IDE. Don't sweat it, I'll have to package it up like a good boy. Appreciate your help though. :)

Comment: @gfmoore Have you solved your error? I am getting the same one...

Comment: Ingo's first solution to build a working executable (in a folder with all the junk) seems to work, though for my app using mapsui I don't get the map to appear at first as I do when I run from Visual Studio. After that it is fine(ish) But I have not yet got a solution for a standalone exe. I raised this issue in the .net Maui Github, but as per usual they don't seem very interested. I've still not bothered to wrap it up in the installer as I have a (faint) hope that as more people use Maui the clamour for resolution might prompt them to take action.

Comment: @gfmoore I don't get why this isn't a priority. Regardless of whatever hip installation process is the flavor of the day, running any .exe file as an end user should be possible with all the security implications that entails, and has always entailed. How is Microsoft expecting developers to migrate from WinForms and the like without basic functionality like this? You'd have thought from Windows 8 and the Microsoft Store failure that they've realized by now that users enjoy freedom, and not being forced into a shoehorned box without options.

Comment: @user4779 they're trying to be apple, but even swift/swiftui has this functionality

Answer (score 9):

#### My MAUI project targeting .Net 7

1- Add a `<WindowsPackageType>` node to your .NET MAUI csproj file:

```
<WindowsPackageType Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">None</WindowsPackageType>
```

[image]

2- In your **launchSettings.json** set `commandName` to `Project`

[image]

3- Build your project in `Release` mode

4- Right click on the project -> Open Folder in File Explorer

5- The **exe** file located in: bin -> Release -> net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -> win10-x64

Comment: After adding this `dotnet publish` also works

Comment: The commands in the accepted answer also work well in this config (using dotnet 6.0)

Comment: Tried that approach with the latest .NET8.0. That did not work.