# Errors when trying to publish .Net Maui project after previous success

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui

I have been working on a .Net Maui app to replace a Python app I built for my company's payroll team. Several previous iterations of this app have allowed me to publish via sideloading. However, I have been unable to publish a new version for a couple of days now.

If I try to publish via sideloading, I get the following error:

> MSB4057 The target "_GenerateAppxPackage" does not exist in the
> project.

--this error claims to be stemming from line 1 of my .csproj file.

I attempted another route to publish it as an executable file following the answer provided in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70097744/publish-net-maui-application-as-windows-executable), and received the following error:

> C:\User\MyFirstName : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.

As well as another error that says looking for the manifest existed with a code 31.

Further up, before that error hits, there is a line that says:

> Skipping target "MauiGeneratePackageAppxManifest" because all output
> files are up-to-date with respect to input files.

I am running VS 17.4.0 Preview 3.0 on Windows 11. I have tried to roll back my code through git (up to 3 versions back), as well as copying local files into a new project, and I get these same errors every time.

It may also be worth mentioning that my Windows Defender and Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool both updated between when I was last able to publish successfully and when the problem arose. I had also updated Visual Studio, but tried to roll that back and publish, and it received the same errors.

Is there anyone who can help me figure out what is going on here, or point me in the right direction? I can provide code samples if need be, though on a limited basis because this is a private project.

Comment: Have you followed the steps included in document : [Publish a .NET MAUI app  for Android/ IOS/Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview) ?

Comment: I had used this process originally, and for some reason I cannot recall, dismissed it in favor of sideloading through the "Publish" selection available in various menus in VS, pushing this method completely out of my mind. Tried it this morning and... It worked!!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I did have an error when trying to install that I have seen a few times, so just in case anyone sees this in the future and runs into the error message:

App installation failed with error message: The current user has already installed an unpackaged version of this app. A packaged version cannot replace this. The conflicting package is [your package] and it was published by CN=[publisher].

I was able to resolve this issue with [this solution](https://www.pmichaels.net/tag/the-current-user-has-already-installed-an-unpackaged-version-of-this-app/).

Comment: As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems.  Thanks for your support for maui.

Comment: I'm encountering this error after updating to v17.4.0 Preview 4.0 and attempting to publish for Windows platform in Visual Studio. I've also noticed that the publish wizard isn't asking me to select a publishing profile - the combo box shown in the docs isn't even 
visible. Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this while using the publish option in Visual studio, then tried publishing from the terminal and it worked. Try this

```
cd <PathToYourMauiProjectFolder>
```

```
dotnet publish -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0  -c Release /p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can refer to document : [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Android/IOS/Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview).

Above documents explain the steps to publish android, ios and windows app, respectively.

You can follow the steps step by step. Under normal circumstances, there will be no problem.