# How to build MAUI.NET solution with few projects into standalone exe file

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, exe, maui

I have solution - MAUI.NET application that has references to other projects in this solution. I have created them all for .NET 6 and all of them were upgraded to .NET 7.

I need to ship this application as .exe file to the user. I found a nice command I am trying to execute in Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022:

```
msbuild /restore /t:build /p:TargetFramework=net7.0-windows10.0.19041 /p:configuration=release /p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:WindowsPackageType=None /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win10-x64
```

also I proceed this with `dotnet restore` and `msbuild /restore`.

I also did addition of `<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>` into .csproj of the main project in solution and changed "commandName" in launchSettings.json into `Project`.

Visual Studio was updated yesterday - 17.4.5. NuGet package manage is 6.4.0 version.

The application runs in debug well.

1. Is it possible to build this for Windows as .exe that can be moved away (without the whole stuff in /bin)?
2. What else I miss to build this way?

I am getting an errors like follows:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'C:\...\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'C:\...\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net7.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
```

Comment: I saw a similar error on github, you can check it out. Does this method help you:[doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7790#:~:text=I%20was%20able%20to%20work%20around%20the%20issue%20by%20removing%20the)

Comment: Unfortunatelly this does not resolve my problem. Anyway - thank you very much for a hint.

Comment: It is said in Maui's Publish Windows official document: .NET MAUI currently only allows publishing an MSIX package. You can't yet publish a Windows executable file for distribution. But I found a thread ([Publish .net MAUI Application as windows executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70097744/publish-net-maui-application-as-windows-executable)), you can try its answer .